# What is the significance of the tattoo on Joker's head?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad

I saw Suicide Squad recently, and wasn't able to be fast enough to read what was tatooed on the Joker's face.

Is there any significance to it? Or is it just part of the appearance like all the other tatoos?

Comment: It says "Damaged", and I heard that was partially intended as a reference to a past incarnation of the Joker who got shot in the forehead. But I have no sources, so comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The director recently explained](http://www.cinemablend.com/news/1544089/the-real-reason-the-joker-has-that-damaged-tattoo-in-suicide-squad):

> David Ayer recently opened up regarding the iconic psycho's "damaged" tattoo, and how it specifically relates to the death of Jason Todd a.k.a Robin. [He elaborated](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/suicide-squad-spoilers/):
>
> > This is sort of my personal thing and maybe less about a larger connection. But Joker killed Robin and Batman basically smashes his teeth out and locks him up in Arkham Asylum. It's in the asylum where **Joker would have done the 'damaged' tattoo as a message to Batman saying, 'You've damaged me. I was so beautiful before and now you've destroyed my face.'** That's where the grill comes from.
>
> David Ayer spoke to Empire and explained that The Joker's metallic teeth and his "damaged" tattoo both have roots in Batman's *A Death in the Family* storyline.